# Dialogue box issue while opening any Microsoft Office File

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

Whenever I try to open any Microsoft office file, I am suddenly getting the below dialogue box for my office account, in the forefront of the file.

Note: I am logged in with my Microsoft office account in Windows 11 laptop.

[image]

[image]

As you can see below the Continue Box is greyed out, and I am just not able to go past that. As a result, I am not able to do anything with Word, Excel, PPT etc.

Things I tried so far:

1. Force stopping WORD.EXE from Task manager and reopening word file - doesn't work
2. Force restart of system and reopening file - doesn't work
3. Try to open Word/Excel as Administrator - doesn't help
4. Disable auto sign-in to One-Drive and then restart system - doesn't work.
5. Clicked on "Learn More" hyper link in dialogue box, which takes me to the Microsoft Page
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/your-microsoft-account-your-data-your-choices-7efd7da0-9683-45f3-9e32-9e9dc90b8ebb

But even after scrolling the whole page, the Continue Button on the dialogue box doesn't work.

Please help. I need this dialogue box to go, before I can do anything with Microsoft Office files.

[image: Dialogue Box]

Answer (score 0):

The only option I found was resetting my laptop. Only reinstall of Windows and factory installs of MS Office Applications resolved it.

I didn't find any shortcut to resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem. Expand the dialogue box and then the Continue button becomes active and you can close the box.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I have already mentioned that in the question